# Angular Signlar R event not being destroyed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm using SignalR with my Angular application. I have a few different components listening to different signalr events, so `EntityListComponent` has a `refreshEntityList` listener and `EntityComponent` would have a `refreshEntity` listener. The problem is if I navigate from the `EntityList` to the `Entity` I am still getting the `EntityList` listener running.

Example of how I am setting up the event listeners:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.registerServerOnEvents();
}

private registerServerOnEvents() {
  // server to client
  this.signalrService.hubProxy.on('refreshEntityList', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.toastService.showInfo('Updating Entity List...');
      this.refreshData();
    }});
  });
}
```

Navigation example

```js
 <a [routerLink]="['../entityroute', entityId]">Link</a>
```

Comment: not sure much about `SignalR` but you can destroy all your events listeners on navigation. That should be implemented I guess, you can use `ngOnDestory` life cycle hook of angular

Comment: I was thinking that I may be able to call `SignalR.Hub.Proxy.off` to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to get this to work correctly yet.

Comment: may be you could try this as well in onDestroy method.

Comment: I have found a solution, but it is merely a band-aid, so if someone has a better solution, let me know, but I have set a variable `signalrEnabled` to false in the OnDestroy, and use it in an if statement in the event listener. It is working, but I know that there is a waste of memory going on for the other pages.

Comment: true, agree that.